# Problem zooming in and out with ScrollTop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work on fixing the problem of zooming in and out. Zooming in works excellently as well as zooming out as well, but the problem is when I reach the end of the page or before it, the zoom works perfectly, but when you zoom out, there is a problem with the page as in the attached pictu

[zoom proplem[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyOmy.gif)

See the link for the example problem

https://i.ibb.co/5xS2ksk/ezgif-6-c6507f8cec56.gif

[See the link for the example problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xczng.gif)

my zoom code

```
$("#zoomin").click(function(){
    if(zm < 4.1){
        zm = parseFloat(zm)+0.1;
        var height_t = h0*zm;
        height_t = $(".page:first-child").height();
        $(".page").each(function(){
            var heig  = h0*zm;
            var widt  = w0*zm;
            console.log(widt+"zm: "+zm+"=>"+zm*widt);
            $(this).attr("style"," width:"+parseInt(widt)+"px!important;height:"+parseInt(heig)+"px!important;");
        });
        height_t =  $(".page:first-child").height() - height_t ;
        if($("#pageNumber").val() > 1){
            $("#hululviewer").scrollTop($("#hululviewer").scrollTop()+(height_t*(($("#pageNumber").val()*1)-1)));
        }
        
            $(".page").each(function(cnt,itm) {
        if($(this).width()>340) {
        $("#zoomout").removeClass("zom");
        }

});
    }

});
$("#zoomout").click(function(){
    
    if(zm > 0.2){
        zm = parseFloat(zm)-0.1;
        var height_t = h0*zm;
        height_t = $(".page:first-child").height();
        $(".page").each(function(){
            var heig  = h0*zm;
            var widt  = w0*zm;
            console.log(widt+"zm: "+zm+"=>"+zm*widt);
            $(this).attr("style"," width:"+parseInt(widt)+"px!important;height:"+parseInt(heig)+"px!important;");           });
        height_t = height_t - $(".page:first-child").height();
        if($("#pageNumber").val() > 1){
            $("#hululviewer").scrollTop($("#hululviewer").scrollTop()-(height_t*(($("#pageNumber").val()*1)-1)));
        }
    
    $(".page").each(function(cnt,itm) {
        if($(this).width()<340) {
                $("#zoomout").addClass("zom");

    
        }

});
```

my project link for test

https://www.hululktaab.com/dir/4bf1/lgty/?dir=lg4bf1.txt

I hope to find a solution to this problem, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix my proplem Edit my  code

```
function changePageNumber(id){
    var dataid = id;
    if (dataid > 0 && dataid <=limit ) {
        var scrollTop     = $("img[data-id='1']").offset().top,
        elementOffset = $("img[data-id='"+dataid+"']").offset().top,
        distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
            $("#hululviewer").animate({scrollTop : distance},0 );
            $("#pageNumber").val(dataid);
            slideSelect(dataid);

    }
}

$('#zoomin').click(() => {
    if (zm < 4.1) {
    zm = parseFloat(zm) + 0.1;
    var height_t = h0 * zm;

  height_t = $('.page:first-child').height();
    $('.page').each(function () {
      var heig = h0 * zm;
      var widt = w0 * zm;
      $(this).attr('style',
      ` width:${parseInt(widt)}px!important;height:${parseInt(heig)}px!important;`);
  });
    height_t = $('.page:first-child').height() - height_t;
    if ($('#pageNumber').val() > 1) {
      $('#hululviewer').scrollTop($('#hululviewer').scrollTop() + height_t * (Number($('#pageNumber').val()) - 1));
  }

            $('.page').each(function (cnt, itm) {
    if ($(this).width() > 340) {
        $('#zoomout').removeClass('zom');
    }
  });
}
});
  $('#zoomout').click(() => {
if (zm > 0.2) {
      zm = parseFloat(zm) - 0.1;
      var height_t = h0 * zm;

  height_t = $('.page:first-child').height();
      $('.page').each(function () {
      var heig = h0 * zm;
      var widt = w0 * zm;

      $(this).attr('style',
      ` width:${parseInt(widt)}px!important;height:${parseInt(heig)}px!important;`);
  });
      height_t = height_t - $('.page:first-child').height();
      if ($('#pageNumber').val() > 1) {
      $('#hululviewer').scrollTop($('#hululviewer').scrollTop() - height_t * (Number($('#pageNumber').val()) - 1));
      changePageNumber(parseInt($('#pageNumber').val()));
  }

      $('.page').each(function (cnt, itm) {
      if ($(this).width() < 340) {
                $('#zoomout').addClass('zom');
    }
  });
  }
});
```